# Approximation/rounding errors in R in simple situations

Tags: r, numeric, numerical-methods

I understand that sometimes in some float number computations, R makes some approximations leading to errors like `9.143243e-16`.

But why can I get a determinant (with `det` command) like `9.143243e-16` when **I only work with 3x3 matrix having only integers numbers**?

Where do the `9.143243e-16` come from, in such a situation where I only had integers numebrs?
Determinants involving integers numbers only should give an integer number, right ?

Thank you in advance.

PS : here is an example (in 4x4, but I could find one in 3x3 as well)  (on R software x86 version) :

```
C=matrix(c(9,3,12,6,-3,-1,-4,-2,2,-2,4,0,5,-1,8,2),4,4,byrow=TRUE)
det(C)
[1] -1.923137e-30
```

Comment: The answer is no. If you divide to integers, you get a floating point, so you can start with integers and get a floating point very easily. Also, instead of forcing us to speculate what the problem is, why not include some sample data, a small bit of code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: `det` is computed outside R by compiled code which expects floating point input.

Comment: nograpes, computing a 3x3 matrix determinant doesn't need division. Only additions and multiplications are enough. Even in float, `1.0000000000000 * 2.000000000000 + 3.0000000 * 4.000000000 + ..` should be something that ends with `.00000000000`, no ?

Comment: nograpes, I also added an example in my question... Something else : how to do some tests like `if (a==0)` ? This is impossible because `0` is sometimes `0` and somtimes something else...

Comment: "Doesn't need" is an anthropormorphization, which you should not do to computer languages because they dislike being labelled that way.

Comment: I don't understand : is it a bad question ? Is it a bad thing to try to understand how this software displays the answers of computations ? "-1" vote for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, you should never expect exact answers from floating point calculations.  You are correct that in principle, the determinant of an integer matrix, which involves only addition, subtraction and multiplication, should give an integer result.  And this would (probably) be the case if R used the naive algorithm to compute the determinant.

However, the naive algorithm involves a summation over all N! permutations, which is enormously inefficient, so instead R uses some other method.  I don't know what this method is -- you can look at the C source if you want, but my guess is that they do a matrix decomposition `X=LU` and then return `det(X)=det(L)det(U)`, where the determinant of `L` and `U` involves simply multiplying the diagonals.

Some more info can be found by looking at the function `det`, shown below.  As you can see, what it actually does is computes the log of the determinant, and then exponentiates it, so there is no reason to believe the result is going to be an integer.

```
> det
function (x, ...) 
{
    z <- determinant(x, logarithm = TRUE, ...)
    c(z$sign * exp(z$modulus))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  What is the `language R` solution then, if I want to do that : `if (det(A)==0) { ... }`  ?

Comment: Something like `abs(det(A))<epsilon` or some small value of `epsilon` (say `1e-12`) should work.  If you have an integer matrix, then the determinant will also be an integer, so it should either be less than `epsilon`, or greater than `1-epsilon`.

Comment: Having to do `abs(det(A))<epsilon` each time I want to test if equal to zero is a bit boring...
Is it possible to configure the software, in order that "if abs(...) is smaller than 1e-14  then display 0"

Comment: Not that I know of.  If it's just about what it looks like, then you can just train yourself to look at `1e-14` and think "zero"...

Comment: you can set up a function `isZ <- function(x) abs(x)<epsilon`; then `isZ(det(A))` is (almost) as compact as `det(A)==0`